# Schauder's theorem: consequences and applications

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

I am about to give an informal talk about Schauder's theorem ($T:X\to Y$ linear operator between Banach spaces is compact if and only if its adjoint is).

Does anyone know any derived theorem/consequence/etc. that I can show? I personally used it only once, but not in a major result, just a computation.

Thank you.